# How to create output_signature for tensorflow.dataset.from_generator

Tags: tensorflow

I have a generator yielding data and labels `yield data, labels` where the data is
an `numpy.ndarray` with variable rows and 500 columns of type `dtype=float32` and the labels are integers of `numpy.int64`.

I'm trying to pass this data into TensorFlow from_generator function to create a TensorFlow dataset: `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) say that the from_generator function needs a parameter `output_signature` as an input. But I'm having trouble understanding how to build this output_signature.

How can I make the output_signature for the generator I described?

Thank you!

Edit:
I used `tf.type_spec_from_value` to get this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
   datagen_row,
   output_signature=(
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)
   )
)
```

But is it correct to use None when the number of rows is varying for the first data type?

Comment: If possible, add some dummy data with generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your datagen_row() function yields input_data, label with format 500 and 1
than your output_signature should be:

```
  output_signature=(
  tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 500), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
  tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

where the first TensorSpec is for the data format and the second one for the label format.
But it would be helpful if you post the function + maybe data examples or data shape here. Otherwise it is hard to help.